# How to get the value of particular get $meta value in wordpress

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I am using this [wordpress Script](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html) to add metaboxes under posts..
I followed as it was written.. but I am having trouble on how to get those values in singe.php
Example an uploaded image
Please guide me on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_metabox_id', true) ) : ?>

        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_metabox_id', true) ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The trick is to use get_post_meta hook

Comment: its still not displaying the value saved.. :(

Comment: post you box creation code here

Comment: are you using it inside the loop?

Comment: no, I am not using it inside the loop, its after `<?php content()?>`

Comment: try: `<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_metabox_id', true); ?>` You need to change the "your_metabox_id" to your metabox id name. you you want to use it outside the  loop use `<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'your_metabox_id', true);
?>`

Comment: What if i needed a url of an uploaded image??

Comment: I believe that we are not talking aboout post thumbnails, right? If you have created metabox with file field you need to call it this way:

`

Comment: not thumbnails, this script allows you to even upload a file or an image.. so was wondering how to get the value of the uploaded file.

Comment: If you have created metabox with file field you need to call it this way:


`<?php 

$t_your_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'your_metabox_id', true); 

$t_your_meta_url = wp_get_attachment_url($t_your_meta);

?>`

Now you can use the $t_your_meta_url in src's of href's

Comment: My pleasure, Nick